# Data type for only lowercase chars

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to make a data type in Haskell that will only match lowercase chars, but not uppercase chars. I'm looking for something like this:

```
data LowerChar = [a..z]
```

Comment: You can not enforce that directly in the type system. You could use `data LowerChar = LowerChar Char` and then keep the constructor private to the module, exporting only a "smart constructor" which does the check.

Comment: This could be done with Liquid Haskell, but in base Haskell this isn't possible.

Comment: You could technically speaking define a sequence of `Lowercase = La | Lb | Lc | ...`, but it probably more effective to add smart constructors to the `LowerChar`, and furthermore you can use [LiquidHaskell](https://github.com/ucsd-progsys/liquidhaskell) to define a subset, and proof code contracts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since there are only 26 characters in that interval, you can represent your type as a finite type of 26 values, using e.g. [`Data.Finite`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/finite-typelits-0.1.4.2/docs/Data-Finite.html):

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
import Data.Finite
import Data.Char

newtype Letter = Letter{ getLetterIndex :: Finite 26 }

toLowerChar :: Letter -> Char
toLowerChar = chr . (+ ord 'a') . fromIntegral . getFinite . getLetterIndex

fromLowerChar :: Char -> Maybe Letter
fromLowerChar = fmap Letter . packFinite . fromIntegral . subtract (ord 'a') . ord
```

Of course, you can interpret the same type into uppercase letters as well if you want to.